# Custom signals from USB

Tags: java, arduino, usb, serial-communication

TL;DR: I need to send custom pulses through a USB cable to an Arduino UNO using Java.

So, what I want to do is to simulate the serial signals from a GPS module to an Arduino UNO.
To do this, I plan to use the signal wires of a USB 2.0 connector with the RX and GND pins of the Arduino.

Because good software is hard to find and this is a good oppurtunity to practise, I would like to write it myself using Java.

Comment: Okay, sounds like a good idea. Go for it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't ask any actual questions, but I suppose if you did ask a question then the answer might be that this project will be impossible.  The low-level USB hardware and drivers do not allow you to send arbitrary pulses as far as I know.

A more reasonable plan to do this simulation would be to get a [USB-to-Serial adapter](https://www.pololu.com/product/1308).  If you install the drivers properly, then you can connect to the serial port from your Java program just as you would connect to any other serial port, perhaps using a Java library like RXTX.